# Angular-Strap 1.2+ modal scrollbar

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-strap

So I made a small mockup up to try angular-strap 1.2+ and are having some trouble with the modal directive.

The modal backdrop displays a vertical scrollbar both while the modal is open and during the fade and scale animations opening and closing the modal. Ie a vertical scrollbar is shown and scaled to the size of the viewscreen and then shrinks down on exit.

Can't seem to find why this is or how I can prevent it.

EDIT: made a plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/9703j1ZeZsCH2enm6apa?p=preview

Comment: Hard to say without seeing it. If you watch DOM style properties in dev tools, you might find something you can override with a css rule (e.g. overflow: hidden). Can you reproduce easily in a Plunker?

Comment: Added a plunker demo to the main question.

Comment: Not seeing scrollbars in the Plunker. Are you?

Comment: Sure am, weird. I'm using Google Chrome 34.0.1847.131 m, says it's the latest version. Maybe temporary bug, I'll restart the browser.

Comment: Tried another computer with the same Chrome version, still see the scrollbar. What browser version are you running?

Comment: Same, but on Mac OS. You must be on Windows - I just checked there and did see the scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide the overflow of the background container:

**CSS:**

```
.modal {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E9Os4KRbKyghp0DWtPfE?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, alot. How did you know/find out the class name was "modal"?

Comment: And an related question if you please. How come the backdrop div is added to the dom (when viewed through the dev tools in Chrome) but not the modal content div? I can't find the html markup for it anywhere?